# VB.net - Derived class from MenuStrip

Tags: vb.net, derived-class

What I am trying to do is make a custom MenuStrip control with several items (Main Menu, Log Out, Exit, etc...) already attached. There would be methods to handle items being clicked. I think this would save me a some redundant code in the long run and I might learn a little something too.

The end product would basically be a custom MenuStrip control that I can throw on my forms and already have the functionality for the items within it.

So my question is, can this be done? I am a novice but if it can be done and is actually a good idea, then I want give it a shot.

Errors abound but this is what I was thinking...

```
Public Class MenuStripCustom
    Inherits MenuStrip

    Add MenuItem(MainMenuToolStripMenuItem)
    MainMenuToolStripMenuItem.Text = Main Menu

        Protected Sub MainMenuNav(e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles MyBase.MainMenuToolStripMenuItem.Click
        MainMenu.Visible = True
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not entirely mistaken you would just be able to do what you are saying. Create a class derived from MenuStrip, add the menuitems in the loading phase, assign the onclick event to whatever function you wan't. However, do realize that the only item you could properly use is Exit. All the other ones will be to program specific and the entire point of this is gone. My 2 cents, stick to a normal menu, set it up and copy it across instead.

Comment: You may be right on program specific, but still want to give it a shot. Do you know how to solve some of the errors in the code block? I am not very familiar with vb.net

Comment: @Meowbits - We can't help you solve the errors if you don't tell us what they are!!  One problem I see, though, is that you are calling Me.Close.  In that context, Me refers to the MenuStrip, and I don't think a MenuStrip has a Close method.

Comment: Good point on the Me.Close, I will be use to adjust that accordingly when I start to add functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, can be done no problems.  Just create a new user control, and make it inherit from MenuStrip.  Then put in code similar to the below for a user control called "UserControl1".

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Inherits MenuStrip

    Private WithEvents NavToolStrip As New ToolStripMenuItem("Nav")

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim tsi As New ToolStripMenuItem
        Me.Items.Add(NavToolStrip)
    End Sub

    Private Sub NavToolStrip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NavToolStrip.Click
        MsgBox("Nav clicked")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Compile the code then you will be able to drag "UserControl1" from your toolbox onto your form.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am struggling to control the items I have added to the ToolStrip. Sorry for asking to be spoon-fed...

Comment: I'm happy to help, just not sure what you mean my "control the items".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just put some comments into your other thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216590/toolstripdropdownitem-how-to-use-correctly-vb-net/13217147#13217147.  I assume that is what you were after.